# Django custom primary key id null error

Tags: python, mysql, django

Consider this model:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=ORGANISATION_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    org_name_lang = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

I get this error on creation, however the instance IS in fact saved:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'organistion_id' cannot be null")
```

Running the create again:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'GB-CHC-202918' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

I'm using mysql, and haven't worked with character primary keys, am I missing out on something?

**update: SOLVED** (there was a related model with a custom save method)

Comment: Are you changing the schema of already existing FOO model or it is an new one

Comment: So, you use Foo() to create the object. I'm just curious if Foo.objects.create() will fire the same error? Anyway this is a strange behavior...

Comment: Yes, create, get_or_create all result in the same error.. Oh the instance IS in fact saved into the database

Comment: Please update your code snippet and error message to match the screenshot, so we can tell what is actually going on.

Comment: Sory, what's the `foo_id` in the error message?

Comment: The problem seems to derrive from a different model that has a foreignkey to organisation

Comment: OK. *Exactly* what are you doing when you get that message? And what models do have an FK to Organisation?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I solved it there was a custom save method in one of the related models that I did overlook (it's not my code)

Answer (score 0):

Each model in Django also has a field `id` which is automatically added and which is used as primary key (see [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)). Django won't add the `id` field when you specify a primary key but since you're getting this error, I'm thinking that you've added your own primary key after creating the table?

If so, you could drop the table and recreate it (`syncdb`) or add a database migration to modify the table structure (e.g., using [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)).

Comment: That's exactly what I thought so I deleted my migrations and tables, and ran syncdb again, but I am still getting this error

Comment: alter your table by dropping the id field

Comment: @shiva what do you mean? there's no id field? In fact even though I get the error the db still creates the item in question